# Abstraction of Apache VirtualHost URL's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, document-root

So I have a couple of mod_rewrite rules to make URL's prettier.

By this I mean I wish to change a url that is entered as such:

```
http://test.domain.com/cheese/wine/
```

to a background association towards the test.php as such:

```
http://test.domain.com/test.php?client=test&page=cheese/wine
```

PS: The client variable above is actually the [test].domain.com.

According to the rewrite log all the RewriteRule's seem to work fine but all I get is a 400 error.

---

vHost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName *.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/dir/

  ...

  RewriteEngine on

  # drop www. from subdomains
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.domain.com$
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://%1.domain.com/$1 [R=301]

  # rewrite x.domain.com/abc to abc?client=x
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com$
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ $1?client=%1 [QSA]

  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ test.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

Edit: The request hostname (*.domain.com) needs to stay intact because (www.)domain.com is treated in a different manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code generates an infinite loop.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName *.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/dir/

  ...

  RewriteEngine on

  # drop www. from subdomains
  # also drop www. from main domain
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*\.)?domain.com$
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://%1domain.com/$1 [R=301]

  # rewrite x.domain.com/abc to abc?client=x
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test\.php
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com$
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ test.php?page=$1&client=%1 [QSA,L]

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I also modified the code so `www.domain.com/` redirect to `domain.com/`

Comment: I see this would work. However I need some alternative solution because (www.)domain.com and *.domain.com should not point to the same DocumentRoot. The other vhost is configured properly and working. Is there any other way to circumvent the infinite loop?

Comment: Huh? I posted the solution to prevent this loop above. As for the domainname stuff, you could just keep using your old RewriteCond if you like. Both should do the same in your setup.